# How to specify a search path with SQL Alchemy and pg8000?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pg8000

I'm trying to connect to a postgres db using SQL Alchemy and the pg8000 driver. I'd like to specify a search path for this connection. With the Psycopg driver, I could do this by doing something like

```
engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://dbuser@dbhost:5432/dbname',
    connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})
```

However, this does not work for the pg8000 driver. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pg8000` pretty much in the same way as `psycopg2`, just need to swap scheme from `postgresql+psycopg2` to `postgresql+pg8000`.

The full connection string definition is in the [SQLAlchemy `pg8000` docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.pg8000):

```
postgresql+pg8000://user:password@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]
```

But while `psycopg2.connect` will pass kwargs to the server (like `options` and its content), `pg8000.connect` will not, so there is no setting `search_path` with `pg8000`.

Comment: while this works without a search path, this errors when I include `connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)}` because pg8000 does not recognize the `options` key.

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#setting-alternate-search-paths-on-connect) describe how to do this. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, text


engine = create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres")

@event.listens_for(engine, "connect", insert=True)
def set_search_path(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    existing_autocommit = dbapi_connection.autocommit
    dbapi_connection.autocommit = True
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET SESSION search_path='myschema'")
    cursor.close()
    dbapi_connection.autocommit = existing_autocommit


with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text("SHOW search_path"))
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

However, as it says in the docs:

> SQLAlchemy is generally organized around the concept of keeping this
> variable at its default value of public